# How to truncate a string in Search Container

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a string which i am displaying in search container, is there a way we can truncate the string and display it up to a limited length.

```
<liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="alert" className="AlertHeader">
    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
        name="Header Id" property="alertHeaderId" value="<%= String.valueOf(alert.getHeaderId()) %>"/>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
        name="Alert Description" property="alertDescription" value="<%= StringUtil.shorten(alert.getDescription(), 20) %>"/>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
        name="Start Date" property="startDate" value="<%= String.valueOf(alert.getStartDate()) %>"/>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
        name="End Date" property="endDate" value="<%= String.valueOf(alert.getEndDate()) %>"/>

    <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text 
        name="Distribution Type" property="distributionType" value="<%= alert.getDistributionType() %>"/>

</liferay-ui:search-container-row>
```

regards

Comment: You can use `StringUtil.shorten(String s, int length)`, to limit the string to desired length.

Comment: Prakash! I tried `<liferay-ui:search-container-column-text    name="Description" property="description" value="<%= StringUtil.shorten(alert.getDescription(), 20) %>"/>` but It didn't work.

Comment: Are you able to get correct value StringUtil.shorten(alert.getDescription(), 20) using this outside this tag?

Comment: Yes that i am able to get it.

Comment: I have updated my question, with my sample code

Comment: I think, it has something to do with `property` attribute, did you try removing this for description?

Comment: @ParkashKumar Yes it worked! Thanks :)

Comment: `StringUtil.shorten` would have been working on its own, but the `property` attribute would be updating `value` of the column.

Comment: Yes! Correct.When removed` property` att.. It worked perfectly fine for me

Comment: I have moved my comments to the answer, you can mark it now to make it useful for the others with similar query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use `StringUtil.shorten(String s, int length)`, to limit the
>   string to desired length.

When using within search container, make sure to remove `property` attribute from `column-text` tag as property attribute will reset value to the original one.